# Terminate current thread in destructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

In a project we're creating multiple statemachines in a wrapper-class. Each wrapper runs in it's own thread. When the jobs is done, the wrapper-class destructor is being called, and in there we would like to stop the thread.

Though if we're using `thread.join()`, we get a deadlock (since it tries to join itself). We could somehow signal another thread, but that seems a bit messy.

Is there any way to properly terminate the thread in which a class is running in, upon object destruction?

Comment: I'm using threads in classes usually with a _has a_ relationship. The class forms the API to steer the things that should be done inside the threading function. If you are using FSMs you may be also interested in my [STTCL](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl) framework.

Comment: Surely when the wrapper's "job is done", the corresponding thread function returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`thread.join()` does not stop a thread. It waits for the thread to finish and then returns. In order to stop a thread you have to have some way of telling the thread to stop, and the thread has to check to see whether it's time to stop. One way to do that is with an atomic bool:

```
class my_thread {
public:
    my_thread() : done(false) { }
    ~my_thread() { done = true; thr.join(); }
    void run() { thread th(&my_thread::do_it, this); swap(th, thr); }
private:
    void do_it() { while (!done) { /* ... */ } }
    std::thread thr;
    std::atomic<bool> done;
};
```

That's off the top of my head; not compiled, not tested.